# how to make old xcode project AppIcon and LaunchImage support iphone6?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-6

I can not see Retina HD 5.5/4.7 items on LaunchImage view of Images.xcassets with old project in latest xcode. It is not a problem If I create a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Select either of the assets. Open the Utilities pane on the right side of Xcode. Show the Attributes Inspector (click on the fat down-arrow icon). Turn on the checkboxes for the iOS 8 / iPhone 6/6+ related icons and launch images.